# C# - Project Deployment (ClickOnce)

Tags: c#, sql-server, clickonce, setup-deployment, prerequisites

I did a project and I used Visual Studio 2017 (Microsoft .NET Framework 4.6.1) - (Windows Form Applications) and SQL Server 2012 Express LocalDB for database operations.

I will run this project on clients' computers. As you can imagine, customers are not interested in database, software, etc. For this purpose, without making any installation on their computers, I'll just make the project work by giving the project file. This is my FIRST comprehensive project.

When I choose deployment attributes in "publish", "prerequisities" I ticked "Microsoft .NET Framework 4.6.1 (x86 and x64) and SQL Server 2012 Express LocalDB and I published it with "Download prerequisites from the component vendor's web site.". I test my software and it works fine.

But when I choose "Download prerequisites from the same location as my application", it fails. I researched it on internet but I couldn't find any clear information. I want the user to download the prerequisites from my software file, so I want to choose "Download prerequisites from the same location as my application". I have "SqlCmdLnUtils.msi", "SqlLocalDB.msi", "sqlncli.msi" for both x86 and x64, and I have "NDP461-KB3102436-x86-x64-AllOS-ENU". I think I need to add the installers on my own computer to be able to do "Download prerequisites from the same location as my application".

But I don't know where I should add these installers in "C: \ Program Files (x86) \ Microsoft SDKs" or "C: \ Program Files (x86) \ Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0 \ SDK".

Answer (score 0):

You are right, you have to download the packages first on your development computer.

By default, the path is `%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft SDKs\ClickOnce Bootstrapper\Packages\`

All the steps that are necessary to offer prerequisites from the same location as your application are described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/deployment/how-to-include-prerequisites-with-a-clickonce-application?view=vs-2019).

Comment: Marc, thank you for answer. I added it but important thing is; which location I have to add "SqlCmdLnUtils.msi", "SqlLocalDB.msi", "sqlncli.msi" for both x86 and x64. Thank you again.